# Python convert list to numpy array to do processing?

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing

I am appending to multiple attributes of a class where the size of attribute is unknown, thus using a flexible container like a list.  However, I need to do processing at each step that requires lots of filtering and processing.  Is it best to convert the list to a numpy array for heavy processing?  I want to avoid a bunch of list comprehensions for filtering.  Pseudo-Code looks like this

```
class class1():
    self.var1 = []
    self.var2 = []
    ...
    self.var15 = []

instance1 = class1()

for _ in range(50):
    instance1.var1.append(number)
    instance1.var2.append(other_number)
    ...
    instance1.var15.append(more_number)

    ###### PROCESSING STEP ########
```

Lets say I need to filter var1 where < 50, and use this filtered indices to filter other variables.  I could use list comprehension

```
list_comp = [idx for idx, value in enumerate(instance1.var1) if value < 50]
```

or I could convert to a numpy array

```
np_var1 = np.array(instance1.var1)
idx = np.argwhere(np_var1 < 50)
```

which has built in functions for these types of stuff.  What is the best way to do it?

Comment: The fast builtin `numpy` methods only work with numeric dtype arrays.   There's nothing special in `numpy` to access instance attributes.

Comment: Right, so I meant during the process step I would do something like numpy.array(instance1.var1) and then do the processing.  edited above

Comment: Yes, you can convert a list to an if that's convenient. But does take time, so often sticking with list processing may be faster.  There are trade offs.

Comment: if you want to save space, you can also try with generator instead of list comprehension

Comment: also having that many instance variables look rather cumbersome, maybe a dictionary is better

Comment: @Copperfield How do you do this with a dictionary?

Comment: simple, `var={k:[] for k in range(15)}` with this list comprehension you create as many as those lists initialized on [] or whatever as you want and if you want one in particular call it as `var[n]`. Or with a defaultdict from the collection module